# Stage file proxy - website under shield

Tags: 7

I want to retrieve some images from my website to my local Drupal website but my website is under .htaccess password protect so I need to enter a username and password to login. I know the password and username but when I try to get the images through [stage file proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/stage_file_proxy) it doesn't work and it's probably because the website is under shield. What should I add in my settings.php file in order for stage file proxy to go through the shield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See module's INSTALL.txt file:

> If the site is using HTTP Basic Authentication (the browser popup for
>   username and password) you can embed those in the url. Be sure to URL
>   encode any special characters:
>
> For example, setting a user name of "myusername" and password as,
>   "letme&in" the configuration would be the following:
>
> $conf['stage_file_proxy_origin'] =
>   'http://myusername:letme%26in@example.com';

Another way, if you have a static IP, is to bypass the Apache auth for certain IP addresses.